# Ventana entrada de datos con tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

Quería implementar una ventana, usando Python y Tkinter, la cual permita al usuario ingresar diferentes datos y estos se muestren justo debajo. Así mismo, quería modificar el logo que viene por defecto en la ventana. Para ello en la misma carpeta donde tengo el módulo incluí el logo, con extensión `.ico` pero obtengo el error `_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "Logo": no such file or directory" not defined`. También probé sin mencionar la extensión, pero obtengo el mismo error

De igual modo, quería saber si existe alguna herramienta que a partir del código documentado genere la propia documentación de uso.

Adjunto el código y el "prototipo" de lo que quiero desarrollar

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox


def ventanaCapturaDatos():

    def devolverDatos():
        textoCaja=entryTexto.get()
        texto.set(textoCaja)
        root.destroy()


    root=Tk()
    root.title("Entrada de datos")

    #FRAME DE ENTRADA DE DATOS

    miFrame=Frame(root)
    miFrame.pack()

    texto=StringVar()


    #ENTRY 

    entryTexto = Entry(miFrame, justify=CENTER ,textvariable=texto)
    entryTexto.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
    root.iconbitmap('Logo.ico')         # No consigo que el logo se muestre
    root.geometry('350x200')

    #BOTÓN ACEPTAR

    botonAceptar=Button(miFrame, text="Aceptar", command=lambda:devolverDatos())
    botonAceptar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="e", padx=5, pady=5)

    root.mainloop()

    return texto.get()


print("Llamamos a la ventana de entrada de datos")

texto=ventanaCapturaDatos()

print("El texto que has introducido es:")
print(texto)
```

[image: "Prototipo de lo que quiero implementar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En cuanto a lo de modificar el icono del programa, yo tuve el mismo problema en *Kubuntu 18.04* y nunca supe el motivo, pero lo solucioné redefiniendo la función `root.iconbitmap` así:

```
root.iconbitmap = lambda icon_path: root.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', root._w, PhotoImage(file=icon_path))
```

Ahora si ejecutas `root.iconbitmap('icon.ico')` debería funcionar.

Para mostrar los datos introducidos por el usuario puedes utilizar un `Listbox`. Si la cantidad de datos es arbitraria lo ideal es que la lista sea *scrollable*. Dentro de la función `ventanaCapturaDatos` puedes crear un `Frame` que contenga un objeto `Listbox` asociado a un objeto `Scrollbar`:

```
# Define un frame hijo de root y muestralo
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack(side=BOTTOM, expand=True, fill=BOTH)

# Define un scrollbar y un listbox hijos del frame
scrollbar = Scrollbar(frame)
listbox = Listbox(frame)

# Asocia el listbox y el scrollbar
listbox.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)

# Muestra el listbox y el scrollbar
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
listbox.pack(side=LEFT, expand=True, fill=BOTH)
```

Ahora simplemente debes modificar la función `devolverDatos` para que agregue el *texto del entry* al *listbox*:

```
def devolverDatos():
    listbox.insert(END, entryTexto.get())

# Puedes implementarlo como una función lambda
```

En cuanto a lo del código documentado sinceramente no tengo ni idea, no documentar el código es uno de mis malos hábitos jeje. Un saludo.